# Какие кавычки играют роль кавычек третьего уровня?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата

У меня в тексте внутри цитаты выходит цитата с кавычками. Что делать?

*«Другой причиной является то, что сделанный Куном акцент на идею изменения мира требует ответа на вопрос „Что же Кун имел в виду под 'изменением мира'?“, и ответ конструктивиста выглядит наиболее прямолинейным».*

Чем мне заменить значки, в которых содержится выражение «изменением мира»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правила:

Розенталь, "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке", параграф 135, п. 5:

Если в начале или конце текста (цитаты, прямой речи) встречаются внутренние и внешние кавычки, то они должны различаться между собой рисунком (так называемые «елочки» и «лапки»), например: Корреспондент сообщает: «“Баллада о солдате” получила высокую оценку на международном кинофестивале»; Я получил телеграмму: «Приезжаю завтра, остановлюсь в гостинице “Москва”».

Внутренние кавычки принято брать "лапки", внешние -- "елочки".
________________________________________​_____

Плюс от Мильчина, "Справочник издателя и автора", раздел 8.2.4:

Если по техническим причинам невозможен набор кавычек разного рисунка, кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются. Напр.: "Цыганы" мои не продаются вовсе", -- сетовал Пушкин.

См: [Виды кавычек, правила кавычек и как ставить](https://legart.livejournal.com/512486.html)

Дополнение.

При необходимости используется «перемежающееся» выделение:

Вот что я обнаружил в первом же абзаце: «Истопник заворчал: „Эх ты, а ещё студент! «Профессор», понимаешь... дифур второго порядка записать не может, а всё туда же.“»

См: [Типографические стандарты: кавычки](http://artefact.lib.ru/design/text_macros_05_quotes_typo.shtml)

Думаю, возможен такой вариант:

**«Другой причиной является то, что сделанный Куном акцент на идею изменения мира требует ответа на вопрос „Что же Кун имел в виду под «изменением мира»?“, и ответ конструктивиста выглядит наиболее прямолинейным».**

Comment: У меня есть внутренние и внешние кавычки, но ещё и кавычки *внутри* внутренних. С ними-то что делать?

Comment: Если позволите: более двух типов допускать не принято (если не используется инонабор), — выделите слова «изменением мира» курсивом или разрядкой.

Comment: На мой взгляд, нужно всеми силами избегать таких ситуаций. А если избежать этого никак невозможно — примените творческий подход.

Comment: При необходимости используется «перемежающееся» выделение (Я дополнил ответ)

Comment: @М_Г Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 6):

У Джона Барта в произведении "Заблудившись в комнате смеха" используется приём рассказа в рассказе. Там как раз яркая иллюстрация этой ситуации: кавычек всего два вида, но они чередуются: «"«""»"» — и так до бесконечности.